# Crosswalk Cordova class CordovaChromeClient doesn't have method "onConsoleMessage"

Tags: java, android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

From this [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onConsoleMessage(android.webkit.ConsoleMessage)) `WebChromeClient` has method `onConsoleMessage()` that I want to override:

My application used Cordova framework and my class is inherited from `CordovaChromeClient`.

So far so good until I migrated to `Crosswalk` framework.

In basic words I replaced Cordova with Cordova provided by Crosswalk. Crosswalk also has `class CordovaChromeClient` but it doesn't have `onConsoleMessage()`.

My goal is to catch JavaScript errors and send report but with Crosswalk I have no clue how to get info what client prints with `console.log(/*  */)`

From [XWalkUIClient.JavascriptMessageType](https://crosswalk-project.org/apis/embeddingapidocs_v2/reference/org/xwalk/core/XWalkUIClient.JavascriptMessageType.html):

I have so far only following options:

```
XWalkUIClient.JavascriptMessageType     JAVASCRIPT_ALERT        JavaScript alert dialog. 
XWalkUIClient.JavascriptMessageType     JAVASCRIPT_BEFOREUNLOAD JavaScript dialog for a window-before-unload notification. 
XWalkUIClient.JavascriptMessageType     JAVASCRIPT_CONFIRM      JavaScript confirm dialog. 
XWalkUIClient.JavascriptMessageType     JAVASCRIPT_PROMPT       JavaScript prompt dialog.
```

Any ideas?

---

I use `crosswalk-cordova-8.37.189.12-arm`